# How to change administrator user when I install an application on GNOME Software

Tags: administrator, gnome-software

When I install an application from GNOME Software it always asks for an administrator password, but the machine has multiple users and I don't know the password.

[image: GNOME Software asking for password]

Answer (score 1):

In Linux when you change any file outside your local home, system will ask you for  the root permissions.

Root is the full permission user that can make changes to system, and for security reasons most distributions disable the root account by default, instead you can use the `sudo` command.

`sudo` is a program for Linux that allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser.

In addition any administrator account will have the sudo ability, So AS an answer for your question, you can enter any password for any user who have this ability.

You can know whom are the users with sudo by running the command:

```
getent group sudo
```

Or you can check the users from settings.

Comment: I have a user with administrator privileges but I've also other users and I want Ubuntu ask me which user to use

Comment: @GiorgiaMarchiori Ubuntu don't know how different users on the system is releated, that is which of the users that are your other users. At the popup, as when you run `sudo` it want your current login-users password.

Answer (score 1):

To install software, you need to have administrator (i.e., root) privileges on your machine. Anyone cannot install software on a system for reasons of security and system stability. The *administrator* or *root* is someone trusted that is permitted to do system interventations.

If you have root privileges, then simply typing your own password will cause the installation to proceed.

If you do *not* have root privileges then, either

- Ask one of the other users that *has* root privileges to install the software
- Ask to one of the users with root privileges to *grant you* root privileges too.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `/etc/group` search for the starting string `sudo` and put your usernamet to the first place after the column like shown here:

```
sudo:x:27: your_username,antea
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the two answers above are outside the scope of the question.

The point is : why gnome-software is asking me the password of another user (that is not me !).

Does it really think that this other user gonna hit its password on my board ?

So the alternative is (for Ubuntu previous than 18...)

```
gksu gnome-software
```

For newest Ubuntu you need to have before :

```
alias gksu='pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY'
```